# Mod Security IIS 10 is blocking PHP interacation even in DetectionOnly

Tags: php, mod-security

I've installed Mod_Security on my IIS 10, i followed directions and ok.
Rename REquest-900*.conf.example to .conf, create rules etc.
If i enable ModSecurity by "SecRuleEngine On" on even if i set it in DetectionMode, all interecation from php pages stop working, for example wordpress login on php form, anything, i can surf but can't have an interaction.

In debug.log i have these errors `[06/Mar/2024:07:10:02.227184 +0100] [SERVER/sid#214b7a32ab0][rid#214b7a34ac0][//xmlrpc.php][2] Warning. Match of "eq 0" against "REQBODY_ERROR" required. [file "C:\Program Files\ModSecurity IIS\modsecurity.conf"] [line "64"] [id "200002"] [msg "Failed to parse request body."] [data "XML parser error: XML: Failed parsing document."] [severity "CRITICAL"]` 
and in line 64 of modsecurity.conf i have this

```
id:'200002', phase:2,t:none,log,deny,status:400,msg:'Failed to parse request body.',logdata:'%{reqbody_error_msg}',severity:2
```

In modsec_audit.log

```
--df680000-F--
HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error
Connection: close
Date: Wed, 06 Mar 2024 06:10:03 +0000
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=UTF-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/10.0
X-Robots-Tag: noindex, follow

--df680000-E--
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<methodResponse>
  <fault>
    <value>
      <struct>
        <member>
          <name>faultCode</name>
          <value><int>-32700</int></value>
        </member>
        <member>
          <name>faultString</name>
          <value><string>parse error. not well formed</string></value>
        </member>
      </struct>
    </value>
  </fault>
</methodResponse>

--df680000-H--
Message: XML parser error: XML: Failed parsing document.
Message: Warning. Match of "eq 0" against "REQBODY_ERROR" required. [file "C:\Program Files\ModSecurity IIS\modsecurity.conf"] [line "64"] [id "200002"] [msg "Failed to parse request body."] [data "XML parser error: XML: Failed parsing document."] [severity "CRITICAL"]
Apache-Handler: IIS
Stopwatch: 1709705402227184 1218771 (- - -)
Stopwatch2: 1709705402227184 1218771; combined=0, p1=0, p2=0, p3=0, p4=0, p5=0, sr=0, sw=0, l=0, gc=0
Response-Body-Transformed: Dechunked
Producer: ModSecurity for IIS (STABLE)/2.9.7 (http://www.modsecurity.org/).
Server: ModSecurity Standalone
Engine-Mode: "DETECTION_ONLY"
--df680000-Z--
```

I really don't know how to fix it, at this time i have to Turn Off ModSecurity

Comment: problem fixed with adding on the config:

SecStreamInBodyInspection On

Now i can enable ModSecurity and website works.

Still remain XML parser error in debug.log "[//xmlrpc.php][1] XML parser error: XML: Failed parsing document." .

Comment: And in event viewer i have this: 

The description for Event ID 1 from source ModSecurity cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.

If the event originated on another computer, the display information had to be saved with the event.

The following information was included with the event: 

Unknown command in config: ModSec